# Scripting with tmux?

Tags: command-line, shell-script, tmux, bash-scripting, layout

Can I script several `bash`/`sh` instructions to open and run in separate `tmux` panes?

I have about 5 or so different commands that need to be executed simultaneously or consecutively.

I usually type them all out manually in their separate panes; I have a bit of a custom layout going on.

Answer (score 4):

If you are already in tmux session, you can execute some command in new window like below:

```
$ tmux neww {command}
```

Also, if you want to split window and execute command:

```
$ tmux splitw {command}
```

Here's some example of running tail -f for several files in the log directory:

```
$ find logs/ -name '*.log' | xargs -n1 -I{} bash -c 'tmux splitw "tail -f $1"; tmux select-layout main-vertical' -- {}
```

`tmux select-layout` part is for fixing pane layout.

---

added as per comment:

You can use:

```
$ tmux new {command}
```

If you aren't in tmux session. So you can combine these like this.

test.sh:

```
tmux new -s foo "bash tmux-test.sh; wait"
```

tmux-test.sh:

```
tmux neww htop
tmux neww htop
tmux splitw htop
```

and then execute test.sh

Comment: Cool, but what if I'm not already in a `tmux` session? I'd like to have it saved it as a `.sh` script (or similar), if possible. I think you might be onto something here. Thanks!

Comment: Windows and panes that are opened in above commands, will close when that `{command}` terminates. For instance `tmux new date` launches new window that executes `date`, and then since `date` command terminates immediately, `tmux` session is also terminated.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.